# How to show different inlines depending of current object field value

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

Given a model named `MainModel` and a `RelatedModel`, where the later has a `ForeignKey` field to `MainModel`:

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.BooleanField()

class RelatedModel1(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeingKey(MainModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RelatedModel2(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeingKey(MainModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and the corresponding ModelAdmin classes:

```
class RelatedModel1InlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RelatedModel1

class RelatedModel2InlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RelatedModel2

class MainModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RelatedModel1, RelatedModel2]
```

And that's the default behavior, you get two inlines, one for every related model. The question is how to hide completely all the inlines when the `MainModel` instance is being created (the `ModelAdmin`'s `add_view`), and to show the inlines for `RelatedModel1` when the `type` field of the `MainModel` instance is `True`, and show the inlines for `RelatedModel2` when `False`.

I was going to create a [descriptor](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) for the `ModelAdmin.inline_instances` attribute, but I realized that I need access to the object instance being edited, but it is passed around as parameters.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I needed that some time ago.. never found the answer, good question!

Answer (score 4):

@Yuji 'Tomita' Tomitayou the idea was good, i had the same but once trying, i realized you must also remove specific key from `self.inlines` because in `change_view` and `add_view` method `self.get_inline_instances(request)` is called before `get_formsets()`. Therefore i moved inlines handling to `get_form()` method.

Here is how i sucessfully did it:

```py
class SampleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = []

    def get_inlines(self):
        return [SampleInline, SampleInline2]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # due to django admin form fields caching you must 
        # redefine inlines on every `get_form()` call
        if (obj): self.inlines = self.get_inlines()
        for inline in self.inlines:
            # Here change condition based on your needs and manipulate
            # self.inlines as you like (remove, change, etc). 
            # I used inline.__name__ to detect if this is correct inline 
            # for my obj
            if obj.CONDITION:
                self.inlines.remove(inline)
        return super(SampleAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question's a bit old and the codebase has changed a bit; there's a cleanish point to override things at now: `get_inline_instances`. You can do this:

```
class MainModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RelatedModel1InlineAdmin,RelatedModel2InlineAdmin]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        #Return no inlines when obj is being created
        if not obj:
            return []
        unfiltered = super(MainModelAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
        #filter out the Inlines you don't want
        if obj.type:
            return [x for x in unfiltered if isinstance(x,RelatedModel1InlineAdmin)]
        else:
            return [x for x in unfiltered if isinstance(x,RelatedModel2InlineAdmin)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need just simply override `change_view` in ModelAdmin:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    obj = self.model.objects.filter(pk=object_id).first()
    if not obj:
        self.inlines = []
    else:
        if obj.type is True:
            self.inlines = [RelatedModel1InlineAdmin]
        else:
            self.inlines = [RelatedModel2InlineAdmin]

    return super().change_view(request,object_id,form_url=form_url,extra_context=extra_context)
```

that's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me while searching for an answer to the same problem in this old post.
Expanding upon darklow's answer , I think you can simply override `get_inline_instances` completely and add an extra check based on your type.

1. Add a boolean type check method in your model

   ```
   class MainModel(models.Model):

       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

       type = models.BooleanField()

       def is_type1(self):

          return type=="some value"

       def is_type2(self):
           return type=="some value"
   ```
2. Add inline instance base on type check - Simply copy and paste the get_inline_insances method from the parent class into your admin.ModelAdmin class and add the if block to check the model type as shown below

   ```
   class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

       inlines = [RelatedModel1, RelatedModel2]

       def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
           inline_instances = []
           if not obj:
               return []
           for inline_class in self.inlines:
               inline = inline_class(self.model, self.admin_site)
               if request:
                   if not (inline.has_add_permission(request) or
                               inline.has_change_permission(request, obj) or
                               inline.has_delete_permission(request, obj)):
                       continue
                   if not inline.has_add_permission(request):
                       inline.max_num = 0
               if obj.is_type1() and isinstance(inline,RelatedModel1InlineAdmin):
                   inline_instances.append(inline)
               if obj.is_type2() and isinstance(inline,RelatedModel2InlineAdmin):
                   inline_instances.append(inline)

           return inline_instances
   ```

Answer (score 1):

From peeking at `contrib.admin.options.py`Looks like you could override `ModelAdmin.get_formsets`. Note that the admin site populates `self.inline_instances` at `__init__`, so you probably want to follow and not instantiate your inlines over and over. I'm not sure how expensive it is : )

```
def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if not obj:
        return [] # no inlines

    elif obj.type == True:
        return [MyInline1(self.model, self.admin_site).get_formset(request, obj)]

    elif obj.type == False:
        return [MyInline2(self.model, self.admin_site).get_formset(request, obj)]

    # again, not sure how expensive MyInline(self.model, self.admin_site) is. 
    # the admin does this once. You could instantiate them and store them on the 
    # admin class somewhere to reference instead.
```

The original admin `get_formsets` uses generators - you could too to more closely mimic the original:

```
def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
    for inline in self.inline_instances:
        yield inline.get_formset(request, obj)
```

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work, because this in the ModelAdmin's `change_view`/`add_view`: `for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request, obj), self.inline_instances):` Thus, a list with one formset is returned, but when it gets "zipped" with a list of inlines, not always the formset returned corresponds to the first inline in the list.

Comment: Ouch, you're right! I'm not sure I see a good way around that self.inline_instances call. A lock to render a view at a time? :( Dang. I was actually pretty excited about this idea because I've run into it myself.

Comment: What about this: `get_formsets` should return Formset instances, so, what about "disabling" those that aren't related to the value of `obj.type`?

Comment: @Mandx interesting... how would you disable it? Setting up a dummy FormSet that accepts any model and overrides the queryset to return nothing would work I think. But at this point in hackery I would suggest disabling them through JavaScript (hiding them) with ModelAdmins support for custom JS scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code I wrote when I was faced with the same problem. It is a bit brute force style, I guess, but is very agile and should suit all cases.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.inline_instances_hash = {}
        for inline_class in self.inlines:
            for inline_instance in self.inline_instances:
                if isinstance(inline_instance, inline_class):
                    break
            self.inline_instances_hash[inline_class] = inline_instance

    def get_inline_instance(self, inline_class):
        return self.inline_instances_hash[inline_class]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.inline_instances = []
            if self.CONDITION:
                self.inline_instances.append(self.get_inline_instance(
                    THE_INLINE_CLASS_I_WANT))
            #...
        else:
            self.inline_instances = self.inline_instances_hash.values()
```