# How can I show inlines dynamically in django admin

Tags: python, django

I want to show inlines dynamically depends on model value. When I override `get_inlines` like:

```
# ModelAdmin
def get_inlines(self, request, obj):
    if obj.is_show:
        return [SectionInline]
    else:
        return []
```

I got exceptions when I change the model object:

```
ValidationError: 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'
```

Seems it not working.

Can anyone help me to figure out the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is override `change_view` not `get_inline`:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
      self.inlines = []
      obj = self.model.objects.filter(pk=object_id).first()
      if obj and obj.is_show:
          self.inlines = [SectionInline]
      return super().change_view(request,object_id,form_url=form_url,extra_context=extra_context)
```

reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074161/how-to-show-different-inlines-depending-of-current-object-field-value/65387225#65387225)